# Oracle virtual box (6.0.10) exiting and erroring when the minikube start is ran

Tags: windows, kubernetes, virtual-machine, virtualbox, minikube

My Oracle virtual box (6.0.10) is exiting when I run the minikube start command. Below is the VBoxHardening.log towards the end file content showing some problem. Please provide me some clue to resolve this.

```
39f8.5258: \SystemRoot\System32\privman64.dll:
39f8.5258:     CreationTime:    2017-06-22T16:52:44.000000000Z
39f8.5258:     LastWriteTime:   2017-06-22T16:52:44.000000000Z
39f8.5258:     ChangeTime:      2019-08-04T03:13:22.783874200Z
39f8.5258:     FileAttributes:  0x20
39f8.5258:     Size:            0x39100
39f8.5258:     NT Headers:      0xf8
39f8.5258:     Timestamp:       0x594be02a
39f8.5258:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
39f8.5258:     Timestamp:       0x594be02a
39f8.5258:     Image Version:   0.0
39f8.5258:     SizeOfImage:     0x3a000 (237568)
39f8.5258:     Resource Dir:    0x38000 LB 0x578
39f8.5258:     [Version info resource found at 0x80! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x0)]
39f8.5258:     [Raw version resource data: 0x380a0 LB 0x37c, codepage 0x4e4 (reserved 0x0)]
39f8.5258:     ProductName:     PowerBroker for Windows
39f8.5258:     ProductVersion:  7.3.0.0
39f8.5258:     FileVersion:     7.3.0.0
39f8.5258:     FileDescription: BeyondTrust PowerBroker for Windows DLL
39f8.5258: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
39f8.5258: Calling main()
39f8.5258: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0
39f8.5258: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
39f8.5258: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
39f8.5258: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 24202 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
39f8.5258: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #2
39f8.5258: Error (rc=-5640):
39f8.5258: More than one thread in process
39f8.5258: Error -5640 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=1)
39f8.5258: More than one thread in process
39f8.5258: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
39f8.5258: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll)
39f8.5258: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
39f8.5258: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\windows\System32\ntdll.dll (Input=ntdll.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000801:<flags> [calling]
39f8.5258: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffbc3730000 'C:\windows\System32\ntdll.dll'
3078.6bc: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 48 ms, the end);
```

Comment: If running a command inside a VM crashes the hypervisor - it's a bug, please report it.

Comment: Which version of windows are you running? Do you have any other hypervisors installed (vware, hyper v, ...)

Comment: @zerkms . I am not running the 'minikube command' in VM . I am runnit it in windows cmd prompt and when it is run it tries to take the minikube ISO image and tries to run it in current VM installation (6.0.10) in the system and thats when i get this error.

Comment: @Zerkms  below is the error in cmd prompt I get   --------------------X Unable to start VM
* Error:         [VBOX_HARDENING] create: creating: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'minikube' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\cygwin64\home\Doraa\.minikube\machines\minikube\minikube\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'

Comment: @Thomas yes hypervisor is installed and I see when i do a systemInfo in cmd prompt :-                                                                                                                      Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Comment: You must install PowerBroker for Windows, it is not compatible with VirtualBox.

Comment: @Thomas no I havent installed powerBroker in my machine at all.

Comment: It is showing up in your logfile. Is your machine managed by someone else?

Comment: @Thomas now i get it after some reading . So the laptop I am working on is my office laptop which is managed by them and I guess they are doing the powerbroker management. Is there a way to disable it ?

Comment: You should discuss this with your admin.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I will try talking to them today

Comment: @Thomas yes accepted. So finally getting my own personal laptop to further work and learn kubernets lol.

Comment: If you just want to learn, have a look at https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/ as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the PowerBroker for Windows from BeyondTrust it will prevent VirtualBox and minikube from running properly. Uninstall PowerBroker is the only documented solution.